# C# data annotation for values in list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, .net-7.0

In a .NET 7 application that uses the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0), is it possible to add data annotations that apply not to a collection, but to the values inside the collection?

I have a config takes takes a list of enum values as input and I want to add the `EnumDataType` annotation so that only actual enum values are allowed. I tried adding the annotation directly to the list property, however, the validation fails with the message `The field Days is invalid.`.

Here is a minimal reproducing example:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

var c = new MyConfig();
Validator.ValidateObject(c, new ValidationContext(c), true);

class MyConfig
{
    [EnumDataType(typeof(DayOfWeek))]
    public List<DayOfWeek> Days { get; set; } = new() { DayOfWeek.Monday };
}
```

Comment: Is `EnumDataType` specifcally documented to work with `IOptions` in .NET Core? Because my understanding of `EnumDataTypeAttribute` is that it's for _scalar_ properties (e.g. mapped to columns in EF or DynamicData, or for the PropertyGrid in WinForms), otherwise it's meaningless to apply it to a `List<DayOfWeek>` (which is already transparently a list-of-an-`enum`-type), so I'm curious why you're adding that attribute in the first place - what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you wanna achieve a scenario that `Days` can only accept the value from a specified enum class?

Comment: In C#, an enum may contain a value that is "out of range". For example, I can cast the integer 42 to `DayOfWeek`, which means that the value is none of `Sunday`, `Monday`, etc. For single values, the `EnumDataType` annotation ensures that only enum values that have a name are allowed. I want to ensure this for all values in the list.

Comment: @pschill As a stopgap, the documentation says your options class can implement `IValidatableObject` and you can put that validation logic in the `Validate(ValidationContext)` method for now.

Comment: Okay I can try this. I had hoped that my use case is common enough so that there already is another solution (like wrapping the attribute in another attribute). I mean, the enum is rather specific, but I can also imagine `List<string>` with the `StringLength` attribute, so that only strings with a specific length are allowed.

Comment: @pschill To my knowledge, the attributes in `DataAnnotations` have _never_ supported being used as validators for elements of collection properties.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Then I guess I need to use custom validation, e.g., `IValidatableObject` or a custom data annotation.

Answer (score -1):

You can archive that thing in simple way. There are 2 ways you can do.

1. If you use Newtonsoft as de/serialization. You can utilize StringEnumConveter as below

```
    builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    })
```

2. Or you want to use StringEnum for specific Enum object then adding this attribute
   `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))`

And your class option just use data annotation JsonProperty for collection as its name when parsing.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's problem: they're trying to use automatic validation of `IOptions` for DI config in .NET Core, which has little to do with JSON, or even string-enums (and .NET uses its own JSON handler for configuring IOPtions from JSON files).